# java Stream a custom Class

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am making a chess game and I am working right now that validates whether the Piece selected by the Player actually belongs to the Player (and not the other player). So I need to check the array of Pieces that belongs to the player and see if the specific Piece is there.

I recently learned about lambdas and streaming so I decided that this would be a good place to attempt to utilize those rather than a simple enhanced-for loop. But I am getting the following error message-

`Cannot invoke stream() on the array type Piece[]`

I have only ever used stream for primitive values but my google searches for how to stream objects has failed to turn up relevant information. Anyways, hopefully this isn't a noob question. Here's my code

```
public boolean hasPiece(Piece piece) {      
    lambdaContains runCheck = arr -> {
        boolean result = arr.stream().anyMatch(x -> x == piece);
        return result;
    };
    return runCheck.doesHave(team);
}


interface lambdaContains {
    boolean doesHave(Piece[] team);
}
```

Edit: it was indeed a dumb error. Lovesh posted the correct answer, which I had tried except I hadn't realized I needed to import java.util.Arrays
Thanks to all!

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, but you can stream an array with `Arrays.stream(arr)`

Comment: You can also simply use `Arrays.asList(arr).contains(piece)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.stream()`

```java
public boolean hasPiece(Piece piece) {      
        lambdaContains runCheck = arr -> {
            boolean result = Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(x -> x == piece);
            return result;
        };
        return runCheck.doesHave(team);       
    
    }


interface lambdaContains {
        boolean doesHave(Piece[] team);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that before but I didn't realize that I had to import java.util.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something more simple (assuming your array is `Piece[] arr`):

```
public boolean hasPiece(Piece piece) { 
    return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(p -> Objects.equals(piece, p));
}
```